# Dealing with linked mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database for this example we'll name them a & b.

**Table a has the following:** 
- id (AI) - Primary Key 
- name 
- img_dir - Foreign Key which references table b's id

**Table b has the following:** 
- id 
- image_paths

I then have a form which takes user data:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="project_name" placeholder="Project Name" />
        Send these files: <br>
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /> <br/>
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send files" />
</form>
```

On submission of the form, I want to be able to create a new tuple in table a storing `project_name` but also create a new tuple in table b to hold the image paths respectively.

I've already grabbed all of the information so thats not the issue, i'm just getting a bit confused on how I would actually create both the entries automatically upon form completion.

Currently, my script inserts the relevant values within table a, but again, the confusion is how to properly synchronise the upload of both.

**script.php**

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']) {

        $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO projects (name) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $proj_name);

        $proj_name = $_POST['project_name'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Note: `reArrayFiles()` is a simple function I implemented to re-arrange the array holding the multiple images:

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}
```

How would I go about creating a new entry in a, and then storing the image paths in b so they're linked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong database design. Table `b` must have reference to table `a` id

Comment: Ok, i've changed the design. How would I go about executing the required query?

Comment: One after the other using [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the ID of the A row you create

Comment: Ah, thats what I was after. thanks @RiggsFolly